# API version AnchorPane.topAnchor FXML attributes?

Tags: javafx-2, fxml, javafx-8

I am trying to figure out the JavaFX API call-equivalent to the FXML AnchorPane.topAnchor (and bottom, right, left anchors) attributes.  Generally the FXML attributes seem to be properties on the object, but there does not appear to be a AnchorPane type property or any other property that returns this type of object.

For example, if I have the following FXML

```
<BorderPane fx:id="borderPane" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="4.0"
    AnchorPane.leftAnchor="4.0" 
    AnchorPane.rightAnchor="4.0"
    AnchorPane.topAnchor="30.0"> .... more FXML here
```

What would be the associated Java API call to set the anchorpane anchors?

e.g.

```
BorderPane borderPane = new BorderPane();
//
// What method calls on borderPane would set the anchors?
//
```

Thanks for any pointers.

- chooks

Comment: The AnchorPane [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/layout/AnchorPane.html) tells you exactly how to do this under the **Anchor Constraints** section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
AnchorPane.setLeftAnchor(borderPane, 4.0);
```

etc

See the [Introduction to FXML, static properties section.](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#static_property_elements)

Comment: Thanks - I didn't recall seeing that one particular section in the doc when I read it.